# Which is correct? and why?

Tags: negation

Meine Frau isst Keine Kase?

OR

Meine Frau isst Keinen Kase?

And can anyone please explain why?

Thanks, 
Vish

Comment: Please take the [tour],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That one is easy: **Käse** is masculin, the verb **essen** comes with accusative case (wen oder was esse ich).

That means:

> Meine Frau isst **keinen** Käse (der Käse)

is the right sentence.

If the accusative object is plural or feminine, then it would be **keine**:

> Meine Frau isst **keine** Wurst (die Wurst)
>
> Meine Frau isst **keine** Salate (der Salat - singular, die Salate - plural)